# How to add emoji picker with Vue 3 (is node 0.10.x outdated?)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, emoji

I'm trying to add an emoji picker to my Vue 3 project, but all of the free packages give me this warning:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'onesignal-emoji-picker@1.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.1', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Does that mean these packages use an engine that is outdated? Can anyone suggest a free emoji picker for me to incorporate into my project please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Asking for libs is offtopic on SO. As for this package, it's client side and isn't affected by Node. This just means that it's very stale and you probably need the one that is more up-to-date, and not abandoned, and doesn't depend on jQuery, and probably is suited to be used with Vue